# Best SQL approach to filterable and sortable table view on multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Whats the best approach to achieve this use case? Imagine we have a simple table view on some webpage. For simplicity imagine we have only these 3 columns.

| ID | Name | Same common property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Name from table A | Property from table A |
| 1 | Name from table B | Property from table B |
| 2 | Name from table C | Property from table C |

Data in this table are retrieved from 3 (or generally X) tables and each table has data needed to fill this table.

Filling this table **without sorting and filtering** would be pretty easy, I´d just use `UNION` on selects for each table (or I´d just concat results on application layer)

**But whats the best approach if we want to sort and filter this table, limit page size and allow paging**? (basically "usual" functionality for this kind of table view) In this scenario we just can not union all results as we do not know how to fill page size (let´s say page size is 30).

If I want to filter, for example, on common property that has value `some value` ordered by `id`, retrieving 2nd page - results from 3 unions could have count of 10, 100 and 1000 and I simply do not know how to mix these results correctly.

I´ve been thinking about something like outer joining these 3 tables in one big row and then somehow filtering properties for 3 columns, for each table, but **that does not seem as a good approach for me and performance of this approach would not be good either, I believe**.

In the end I´d like to add that we are talking about SQL, but if there is any extension of something for **PostgreSQL**, it can be used as well.

Comment: I'm not clear why you cannot perform all these filtering and sorting activities after you have UNION'd the three tables. assuming what you are trying to achieve is to treat all three tables as a single dataset? Your statement "results from 3 unions could have count of 10, 100 and 1000" doesn't seem to make sense - after the union there is one result (not 3) and the record count would be 1110

Comment: @NickW Yea, I basically want to union results from 3 tables (as it would one table) and on these unioned results I´d like to perform sorting, filtering and paging if needed. But unioning all 3 tables and then performing sorts looked as not good idea in sight of performance as some of these tables might be really big

Comment: If any filtering can be applied to each individual table then you can apply it in the UNIONs as WHERE clauses. But anything that requires the UNIONed dataset to exist first (e.g. sorting, paging, etc) obviously requires the UNION to have been executed - there's no way round this. Any performance optimisations wouldn't get round the need to run the UNION

Comment: @NickW Allright, that was something I´ve expected a little but wanted to confirm and as there is no better solution to this situation, I have no other choice. Thank you.

Comment: Very unclear what you want here: unions will stack rows (of the same column numbers)  but "**outer joining these 3 tables in one big row**" is wildly different to unions. Do you need to stitch by rows (union) or by columns (possibly via joins)? Do you filter before presenting a page of data - then sort that page, or are you filtering an entire unioned result and then present a page from that result?  How many rows would be in a union of all 3 tables? and Can you just use a view of the wanted columns?  Have you examined any explain plans for such a view? sample data would help

Comment: Is the data volatile or static? i.e. could a timed job prepare a table needed for the front-end derived from the source tables?